# Docklight and Arduino serial communication (sending hex through RS232)

Tags: arduino, serial-port, nodemcu

I have the following code (I'm using Arduino IDE and a NodeMCU with a MAX3232):

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial RS232Serial(D1, D2); // RX | TX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  RS232Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!RS232Serial);
}

void loop() {

  Serial.println("Sending msg...");
  char msg[] = {0x7E, 0x00, 0x78, 0xF0, 0x7E};

  RS232Serial.write(msg, sizeof(msg));

  Serial.println("Waiting incomming message:");
  while(RS232Serial.available() <= 0) {
    delay(1);
  }

  while(RS232Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.print(RS232Serial.read(), HEX);
  }

  Serial.println("");

  Serial.println("------------ END -----------");

}
```

I'm using Docklight to test the communication. So far I'm able to receive the HEX that the NodeMCU boards sends first `char msg[] = {0x7E, 0x00, 0x78, 0xF0, 0x7E};`. But I'm unable to receive the data properly from Docklight.

The HEX I'm trying to send from Docklight is `7E 00 00 70 15 7E`. Debugging with serial monitor, sometimes I receive just `7E` and sometimes `0FF`, never the complete message. Baud rate, start/stop bits and parity are set to default.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

One reason for not working as expected is:

- You are processing the answer as soon as one byte has appeared in the receive buffer.

There is a related example in the Docklight Application Note [Arduino Serial Communication](https://docklight.de/pdf/Docklight_Application_Note_ArduinoSerial.pdf) - check the code listing on page 5. It makes use of the Arduino [SerialEvent() function](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent) to collect the incoming telegram byte-per-byte. Only after receiving the end of telegram mark (here: a line feed "\n" character), it sets a flag that tells the code in the main loop() to do something with the accumulated data telegram.

The SerialEvent approach used in the Docklight exampleis not a must. You can solve this inside loop() alone, too. But you certainly need to change the

```
  while(RS232Serial.available() <= 0) {
```

...

```
  while(RS232Serial.available() > 0) {
```

parts to something that will wait until a full telegram has been received (or a timeout has occurred).

Now what irritates me still is that you write you sometimes receive "0FF" even though you never send it from Docklight. This could indicate still a second problem on the actual RS232 communication, but it's hard to guess without extra information.

But re-working the telegram receiving part as described above should already make things much clearer and then the source of the "0FF" is probably more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
while(RS232Serial.available() <= 0) {
  delay(1);
}
```

You are only waiting for the serial buffer to have at least 1 byte, but you are not guaranteed that your full message (6 bytes) will be present, when you call `RS232Serial.available()`.

You should wait for the serial buffer to accumulate at least 6 bytes, before you try to read them.

```cpp
while(RS232Serial.available() < 6) {
  delay(1);
}
```

They you can read the full buffer with:

```cpp
while(RS232Serial.available() > 0) {
  Serial.print(RS232Serial.read(), HEX);
}
```

or only 6 bytes with:

```cpp
for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
  Serial.print(RS232Serial.read(), HEX);
}
```

---

I don't know about your `0FF`, but `Serial.print(RS232Serial.read(), HEX)` doesn't zero pad the hex string and this could actually be `00 0F 0F` or `00 FF`.

You should print out the bytes with:

```cpp
byte b = RS232Serial.read();
if (b < 16) Serial.print('0'); // zero pad
Serial.print(b, HEX);
Serial.print(' '); // add space after each byte
```